# image using 95% tag not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, image, content-management-system, image-scaling

I'm creating my website [found here](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2), I added my logo at the top of the page.
As this site is a mobile-optimized site, I wanted to add the logo so it correctly scales to the appropriate viewport (device screen size).

I have accomplished this by using this code in my CSS file:

```
.logo{
        width: 75%;
        height: 10%;
}
```

My logo is stored in `header.php`, and is included on all of the respective pages. However, the logo looks good on the homepage, but when clicking one of the navigational tabs to bring up the `list.php` page, it doesn't look scaled correctly.

`header.php` ------------

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" />

</head>
<body width="100%">


<p align="center"><img src="http://www.xclo.co.uk/logomobi.png" onclick="history.go(-1);" class="logo" border="0" width="100%" />


<div class="ribbon"><div class="ribbon-stitches-top"></div><strong class="ribbon-content"><h1><a href="index.php" style="color:#000000;">Home</a> - <a href="search.php" style="color:#000000;">Search</a> - More</h1></strong><div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom"></div></div></p>


<br /><br /><br /><br />

</p>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is:

```
body{
   background-color:#dff7c8;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'CustomFont';
   src: url('fonts/fh_ink.eot'); /* For Internet Explorer 6+ */
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'CustomFont';
   src: url('fonts/fh_ink.ttf'); /* For non-IE browsers */
}

a:link{
        color:black;
        text-decoration:none;
}

.border {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
        Margin-left:auto;
        Margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#c3f495;
        border: 5px ridge #009900;
        border-radius: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);

}

.title {
    font-family: 'CustomFont';
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.5em; 
        color:#000000;
        text-shadow: #999 2px 2px 4px;
}


.content {
        font-size: 15px;
        color:#000000;
}

.search {
        width: 24em;
        height:3em;
        border: 5px solid #009900;
        border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #A4A4A4;
        font-size: 20px; Position:relative;
}

/* (portrait) ----------- */
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait){


.logo{
        position:relative;
        width: 75%;
        height: 10%;
}

.go {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}


.inlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:-15px;
    left:-15px
}

.img {
    position:relative;
    width:201px;    
    height:81px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.img2 {
    position:relative;
    border-radius:20%;
    width:201px;    
    height:81px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.img3 {
    position:relative;
    width:150px;    
    height:81px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.img4 {
    position:relative;
    width:201px;    
    height:150px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.appimg {
    position:relative;
    width:20%;    
    height:20%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.drapp {
    position:relative;
    width:35%;    
    height:15%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.appstoreimg {
    position:relative;
    width:110px;    
    height:40px;
    background-color: transparent;
}


.divider {
    border-top: 3px dashed #009933;

}

li.android, 
li.iphone, 
li.ipad{
  display:none;
}

body.android .android,
body.iphone .iphone,
body.ipad .ipad{
  display:block;
}

}



/*(landscape) ----------- */
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape){

.go {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    height:90px;
    width:90px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}


.inlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:-15px;
    left:-15px
}


.img {
    position:relative;
    width:211px;    
    height:81px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.img2 {
    position:relative;
    width:211px;    
    height:81px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.img3 {
    position:relative;
    width:150px;    
    height:81px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.img4 {
    position:relative;
    width:211px;    
    height:160px;
    background-color: transparent;
}


.appimg {
    width:15%;    
    height:8%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.drapp {
    position:relative;
    width:25%;    
    height:30%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.appstoreimg {
    position:relative;
    width:220px;    
    height:80px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.logo{
        position:relative;
        width: 75%;
        height: 10%;
}

.divider {
    border-top: 3px dashed #009933;

}

li.android, 
li.iphone, 
li.ipad{
  display:none;
}

body.android .android,
body.iphone .iphone,
body.ipad .ipad{
  display:block;
}

}
```

`list.php` ------------

```
<?php

include_once('include/connection.php');
include_once('include/article.php');

$article = new storearticle();

$articles = $article->fetch_all();

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>xclo mobi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" />
</head>

<body width="100%">
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>


<div class="container">
<h6><div align="center" class="title" style="color:#618050;"><b><u><?PHP echo "category = ", htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); ?></b></u></h6></div>


    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { 
    if ($article['promo_cat'] === $_GET['id']) { ?>


<div class="border">
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="<?php echo $article['promo_image']; ?>" border="0" class="img" align="left"><br />


<a href="<?php echo $article['promo_link']; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" title="" src="GO.png" height="50" width="50" align="right" /></a>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
    <?PHP echo '<div class="title">' . $article['promo_title'] . '</div>'; ?>
<br />

<font class="content"><em><center><?php echo $article['promo_content']; ?></center></em></font>

</div><br/><br />

          </a>

 <?php } } ?>

</div>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Could someone please guide me in the correct direction? Thank you.

Comment: No issues on DESKTOP FireFox. ;) I missed the `mobile` part!

Comment: hi. AmazingDreams. where are you looking?

Comment: @KevHopwood What browser are you using? What OS?

Comment: it does it on every browser firefox PC, chrome, IOS Safari and android chrome. the hope page works ok. but click one of my tabs. (for example FREE)

Comment: Try adding min-height: 10%; to your logo???

Comment: i have added that to the logo in my css and still looks the same.

Comment: in the css for your logo

Comment: done. still looks the same

Comment: Ok, you could try what Whistletoe below has said?

Comment: @KevHopwood Your initial logo size is `1,000px × 400px (scaled to 743px × 297px)` - I suggest to use this for ALL your CSS classes (.logo) `width:100%; max-width:743px; max-height:297px;` - I use something to that affect and works beautifully.

Comment: @KevHopwood You could also try `<img style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width:100%;" border=0  alt="LOGO" align=middle src="your_image.xxx"` which is another method I used for a client's website and using a 1800px wide image which renders nicely for large as well as small iPhone screens and will automatically adjust to screen width, without worrying about height attribute.

Comment: hi fred. this works. thank you. i had a go down the @ media query route but it did not work for me. thanks again.

Comment: @KevHopwood Great but what worked exactly? I could make it as an answer if you want, just need to know which one worked.

Comment: ive used the 1st post. but ill give the 2nd one a try.

Comment: @KevHopwood I posted them both in my answer below.

Comment: You are inserting html-head code inside the body-element. Please move <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>.

Comment: @KevHopwood I just visited your Web site and it looks very good. I also reduced my window size and it scaled perfectly.

Comment: Whistletoe, move it to where exactly? thanks fred. any ideas that you would think will work well on my site that I do not have already?

Comment: oh. move it outside the body tag. probs a good idea. might interfere with body codes later on. i have moved it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are a few methods you can try.**

Your initial logo size is `1,000px × 400px (scaled to 743px × 297px)`

I suggest to use this for ALL your CSS classes (.logo)

```
width:100%; max-width:743px; max-height:297px;
```

I use something to that affect and it works beautifully.

**You could also try:**

```
<img style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width:100%;" border=0 alt="LOGO" align=middle src="your_image.xxx">
```

Which is another method I used for a client's website and using a 1800px wide image which renders nicely for large as well as small iPhone screens and will automatically adjust to screen width, without worrying about height attribute.

Comment: hi fred. im i correct in saying that this code `<img style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width:70%;" border="0" src="http://www.xclo.co.uk/logomobi.png" onclick="history.go(-1);" alt="LOGO"  align="middle" />` does not require css?

Comment: @KevHopwood Hi Kev. Am not 100% sure about `onclick="history.go(-1);"` that might belong in your `href` and not in `img`. If `70%` and `onclick="history.go(-1);"` works for you, give it a try and see, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @KevHopwood That's great, I'm glad it worked out for you. If you feel that my answer helped you for a solution, then please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer, so your question will now be marked as solved, cheers :)

Comment: I tried 100% but it looked too big so i played around and it looks ok at 70% on my pc, galaxy s3, ipad and ipod touch. as they are common devices I'm sure it will be safe (dunno about the dreaded blackberry tho).  on click has worked well for me for a few projects. again. can i delete the css for .logo if it will not be needed?

Comment: also. your other code judders when it gets to around 300px in firefox's responsive design view but the img style does not.

Comment: @KevHopwood I suggest you just rename all your `.logo` classes to `.logo_old` for example, just in case you need it for something else down the road. You could then do a "find and replace" with one click. (wink) that's what I do.

Comment: @KevHopwood Yes, I'm aware about the judders. I developped a whole new method to get around that, but is rather complicated and using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove either the width rule or the height rule to keep the image proportions.
Do you want it to be 10% of the height or 75% of the width?

Also remove the

```
width="100%"
```

from inline html. Keep all style rules in external css.

Comment: hi. could you please explain what you mean.

Comment: the only width="100" that was on my list and header page was the body width. both of them have now been removed but still it does not work.

Comment: hi. freds post above makes it look a lot more normal. thanks.

Comment: I see now that you have included the html-head code inside the body element. That should be moved.